# calculating the duration of a keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Here's the Setup:**

I'm using *python* to script a simple driving simulation.
I do want to include the reality of pressing on pedals, by allowing the player to partially press down on the gas/brake/clutch.
The same rule will apply for depressing pedals.

So I get my hands dirty and start coding.
I set the variable *pedalpressed* to 0.0 (float). I want it should modify when the player holds down a key (ex. 'q' key) to climb in count until it reaches 100. I want it to reach 100 in 1.5 seconds.

```
pedalpressed = 0.0
```

So by holding down the 'q' key for 1.5 seconds, the variable *pedalpressed* will climb to  100.
Now if I hold it down for less than 1.5 seconds, the value of *pedalpressed* will not yet have reached 100 and will be set to whatever number it has reached...

```
pedalpressed = 79.34
```

until you press 'q' again (which will then continue from where it is until 100).

```
pedalpressed = 100.00
```

---

**Here's the Question:**

How do I capture the duration of a key-press, and while holding down the key, make a float climb until it reaches a given value. After, how can I do the above within a time-frame of 1.5 seconds?

Comment: There still hasn't been given a useful answer.
Either no-one who has an answer has seen this post, or I need a particular library or plugin in order to capture this data.

Answer (score -1):

Deprends on the tools you're using but general way is to capture both keydown and keyup evenets instead of just one keypress.

```
delta = CurrentTime - keyDownTime; // actual press time
delta = keyUpTime   - keyDownTime; // release - how long was key down ?
```

Comment: Not sure how to incorporate this into my code.

No I am not using any additional libraries or tools. Just plain ol python.